# How to fill a JavaFX table to a TCP Client from a TCP Server which retrieves data from DB

Tags: java, database, javafx, tcp

My task is to send data from a client through the server in a database and retrieve those data through the server and fill some tables.

I can't find a way how to fill those tables in the way I want.

GitHub project [link](http://%20https://github.com/SadriShehu/DistributeSystems).

Client Listener from where I get the data for the client

```
public clientListener(TextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
        int portNr = Integer.parseInt(port);

        try {
            // Create a socket to connect to the server
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", portNr);

            // Create an output stream to send data to the server
            outputToServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            // Create an input stream to read data from the server
            inputFromServer = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText("Exception in gateway constructor: " + ex.toString() + "\n"));
        }
    } 

    public ObservableList<Qyteti> getQytet() {
        outputToServer.println(GET_QYTET);
        outputToServer.flush();
        String ID = null, Qyteti = null, ZIP = null;
        try {
            ObservableList<Qyteti> Qytet = null;
            Qytet.add(new Qyteti(inputFromServer.readLine().concat(ID), 
            inputFromServer.readLine().concat(Qyteti), 
            inputFromServer.readLine().concat(ZIP)));
            return Qytet;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Form Controller

```
public void updateTable() {
    ID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));
    Qyteti.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Qyteti"));
    ZIP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ZIP"));
    QytetiList.add((application.Qyteti) gateway.getQytet());    
    tblQyteti.setItems(QytetiList);
}
```

Server Functions from where in different cases I get different results

```
public void run() {
    handler = new ConnectionHandler();
    try {
    // Create reading and writing streams
    BufferedReader inputFromClient = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter outputToClient = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

    // Continuously serve the client
    while (true) {
      // Receive request code from the client
      int request = Integer.parseInt(inputFromClient.readLine());
      // Process request
      switch(request) {
          case GET_QYTET: {
              connection = handler.getConnection();
              String merrQytet = "SELECT * FROM tblQyteti";
              try {
                  pst = connection.prepareStatement(merrQytet);
                  ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                  while(rs.next()) { 
                    outputToClient.printf(merrQytet, rs.getString("qid"), rs.getString("Qyteti"), rs.getString("ZIP"));
                  }
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(IOException ex) {
        Platform.runLater(()->textArea.appendText("Exception in client 
        thread: "+ex.toString()+"\n"));
  }
```

Qyteti class which is used as an object type:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Qyteti implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String ID, Qyteti, ZIP;

    public Qyteti(String ID, String Qyteti, String ZIP) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Qyteti = Qyteti;
        this.ZIP = ZIP;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getQyteti() {
        return Qyteti;
    }

    public void setQyteti(String qyteti) {
        Qyteti = qyteti;
    }

    public String getZIP() {
        return ZIP;
    }

    public void setZIP(String zIP) {
        ZIP = zIP;
    }


}
```

Comment: Your question needs to have to (shortest possible) code for your problem, end preferably also what you tried so far. No links to something that might be gone when someone else reads this.

Comment: Ok, thank you sir. I'll try to follow your instructions. I'll edit the question.